# How is Chrome SingleFile format achieved?

Tags: html, google-chrome, archive

Chrome has an extension called SingleFile. It basically saves a web page in a one file *.htm page that is a clone of the original website. I have seen something like this done with Mozilla MAFF format. The MAFF format saves the file in *.maf, and is you want to see contents (html, css, images etc.) you can change the format to *.zip. Then you can unzip it. With the SingleFile (Chrome) you can’t unzip the file by changing extension. Does anybody know how this is achieved? Is this a known thing that *.htm can offer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The MAFF format saves the file in *.maf, and is you want to see
> contents (html, css, images etc.) you can change the format to *.zip.
> Then you can unzip it.

I'm assuming that you're really asking just how the image files are stored in .htm since html and css can easily be stored as text in htm.

It uses uuencode/uudecode to embed image files in the .htm file.  More on that here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding

This is why changing the extension to .zip won't turn the file into a zip package that you can unzip.

[Illustrative side-by-side screenshots of external vs. embedded image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JASd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found this article may help: http://www.techgainer.com/enable-single-file-mhtml-support-chrome/

> On Chrome address bar, type chrome://flags, then hit enter. Now use Ctrl+F (Command+F on Mac) bring search bar and search for mhtml as I did below. Once you find the option, click on Enable link.